# Attempt to install PHP 7.4, but get PHP 8.1.2

Tags: apt, package-management, php, php7

For my needs, I need to install `PHP 7.4` (and a module for Apache2), instead of the latest `PHP 8.x`.

So I run the following command: `apt-get install -y php7.4 libapache2-mod-php7.4`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php7.4' for regex 'php7.4'
Note, selecting 'php7.4-fpm' for regex 'php7.4'
Note, selecting 'php7.4-common' for regex 'php7.4'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php8.1 php-common php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline
Suggested packages:
  php-pear
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.4 libapache2-mod-php8.1 php-common php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 840 B/5193 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/universe arm64 libapache2-mod-php7.4 arm64 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2 [840 B]
Fetched 840 B in 0s (23.5 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package php-common.
(Reading database ... 114642 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-php-common_2%3a92ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-common (2:92ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php8.1-common.
Preparing to unpack .../1-php8.1-common_8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-common (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php8.1-opcache.
Preparing to unpack .../2-php8.1-opcache_8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-opcache (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php8.1-readline.
Preparing to unpack .../3-php8.1-readline_8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-readline (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php8.1-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../4-php8.1-cli_8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.1-cli (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php8.1.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libapache2-mod-php8.1_8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php8.1 (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libapache2-mod-php_2%3a8.1+92ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php (2:8.1+92ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php7.4.
Preparing to unpack .../7-libapache2-mod-php7.4_8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php7.4 (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up php-common (2:92ubuntu1) ...
Setting up php8.1-common (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up php8.1-readline (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up php8.1-opcache (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up php8.1-cli (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php8.1 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar8.1 to provide /usr/bin/phar (phar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar.phar8.1 to provide /usr/bin/phar.phar (phar.phar) in auto mode
Setting up libapache2-mod-php8.1 (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
apache2_invoke: Enable module php8.1
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.4 (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up libapache2-mod-php (2:8.1+92ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for php8.1-cli (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php8.1 (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.2) ...
Scanning processes...
Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

but when I checked what PHP version I have installed using `php --version`, I get the following:

```
PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2022 12:10:37) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

#### Question

Why did I get `PHP 8.1.2` even though I explicitly attempted to install `PHP 7.4`? How can I install `PHP 7.4` without any traces of `PHP 8.x`?

Comment: PHP 7.4 is not available in Jammy. It has PHP 8.1, which (apparently) is backward compatible with the Apache2 PHP 7.4 module. If you insist on PHP 7.4, I suppose you'd have to run this on Focal (20.04).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but looks like you're not specifying the *exact* name of the package...
I suggest you find the package name through the `apt-cache policy php7.4*` command
Also, you might look at `apt list |grep php7.4` for modules you might want to add (in your case, I think it's already OK).
With all this, I'd say your final install command line should be:
`sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-common libapache2-mod-php7.4`

Anyway, if both versions still keep being installed, the `sudo update-alternative --config php` should help you deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

On the directory where you want php7.4, create an .htaccess file and add inside it the following :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php4|php5|php3|php2|php|phtml)$">
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php
</FilesMatch>
```

It's usually better to keep the last php version to run on the whole server and only add special cases for each subdomain, directory or whatever file you are using.